# Is it dangerous to call a function that deletes nodes based on criteria while a cron job is running that imports them

Tags: 7, cron

I have custom module that performs a dbquery on a button click that deletes nodes that fit a certain criteria. Is it dangerous that I also occasionally run a cron job that imports nodes that fit this criteria? If I ran both at the same time could something break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the way you import:

1. If you delete the nodes on some criteria and import the nodes as new nodes (`$node->is_new = TRUE`), this shouldn't be a problem.
2. If you are updating the existing nodes while importing and deleting the nodes at the same time, then there could be issues.

This is because the `node_save()` function internally calls [drupal_write_record](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7), which creates a node with an incremental nid value if the `$node->is_new` is set to `TRUE`. Or updates the exiting nodes if you are importing.

Comment: If I was updating existing nodes while deleting, do you know of a way to resolve that?

Comment: If you are sure you are not deleting the node which you will update, you should be fine. You could check for logic in the implementation of both `hook_node_delete`, and `hook_node_update` for checking if you need to delete the updated nodes, or you want to create the deleted node.